# "Venire ad" or "Venire in"?

Tags: word-choice, preposition

When can I use "venire ad", or "venire in". (excepting the few locative cases)

What kind of buildings, place, etc, can accept the one or the other?
Is "venire ad" insists more on the move than "in"?

I've found that bother "in ludum" and "ad ludum" were both possible for instance (go to school), is there a difference in the use or in the meaning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the difference is much like the one between the English "in" and "at" (for being somewhere) or "into" and "to" (for going somewhere).
When you are in the store, you are actually inside it.
When you are at the store, your are probably somewhere near but not quite inside.

For movement, *ad* + accusative means going near and *in* + accusative means going in.
For location, *ad* + accusative means being near and *in* + ablative means being inside.
It's not a question of which place requires which pronoun, but of where you are in relation to the place.

If I plan to meet a friend in front of their house, I could say *ad domum tuam venio*.
If I actually planned to go inside, I could say *in domum tuam venio*.
(Adding an adjective or a possessive pronoun often turns locatives and other non-prepositional expressions for *domus* and cities into normal prepositional phrases.)

Both *in ludum* and *ad ludum* make sense with *venire* but mean different things.
Are you going to the schoolyard or all the way into the building?

This is of course a simplified picture, but should give you a good overall idea of the difference.
One cannot cover everything quite so briefly.
I will also point out that I took the point of view of buildings, not so much places like market squares and in particular not people.

Comment: So, "ad ludum" rather means that you don't attend school but you enter (in) the building?

Comment: @Quidam Something like that. Depends on context. Maybe you're just in front of the building or in the general area.

Comment: I think the English distinction you are looking for is between "into" and "to".

Comment: @CMonsour Indeed! I edited that in.

Comment: I agree with your description of the Latin contrasts involving _in_ vs. _ad_ but I'm not sure about your parallelism with English, in particular, about your statement that "When you are **at** the store, you are probably **somewhere near** but not quite inside". I imagine "at" as involving you're located at some point in the store, rather than near (?) the store. I don't know if any native speaker of English could confirm this.

Comment: I think this whole reply as well as the comments are incorrect: neither "ad" nor "to" imply not being inside. "At the store" is used idiomatically to mean "visiting the store, doing shopping there ", while "in the store" expresses precise physical location. The former normally involves the latter. "I'm going to school" similarly means "heading to the building to take classes", while "to go to school" means "to be a student at school". "I'm going to the school" expresses heading to the school building, and "I'm going into the school" is what's used to purely express entering the building.

Comment: As far as Latin, "ad Jūlium" likewise doesn't say anything about entrering either way, but by default it's understood that if "you're going to Mike's place", you're planning to enter it and not walk around the premises. Thus "cēnāre ad/apud Jūlium" is used to express location, precisely like "I'm having dinner at Mike's" means that you're at Mike's home in metaphorical sense, whether currently inside or outside in physical sense. "Ad Jūlium"/"At Mike's" is by extension used in names of shops, and "venīre ad macellum" is "to go to the market". Meanwhile, "to go to school is "in lūdum venīre".

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian I only wanted to give a simple description of the differences for buildings. I make no claims about people; I did not compare*ad/in Marcum venire*. There are more details than what I gave, but I wanted to just give the main difference in the case of buildings. I would be happy to see you (or anyone else) write a separate answer to tell what I left untold or perhaps told badly.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta But your description is a priori wrong because you get the difference wrong in the language you're describing it with, while also establishing a false correspondence: "at the store" means *in tabernā* and "at school" means *in lūdō* (I've already pointed out the dynamic verbs). The main difference is in how the destination is conceived of by the speaker, but the ultimate usage is not just language-, but collocation-specific. It's impossible to draw such a generalisation for English as you're implying in the first place, let alone extend it to Latin.

Answer (score 1):

A similar source of confusion can arise between movement (accusative) and position (ablative) with preposition "sub" = "under".

"...et omnes milites sub iugum missi sunt." = "...and all the soldiers were sent under the yoke."

(To send an enemy under the yoke [a wooden collar, of long diameter, placed around the neck] was a traditional form of humiliation.)

Astonished to find "sub" taking accusative, when, at that time, had only ever encountered the ablative form. After some effort-of-study (having neglected to consult dictionary) yes, to be sent under the yoke (sub iugum mittere) involves movement; therefore, "sub" takes neuter accusative "iugum", not ablative "iugo". Confusion: a captured soldier is, presumably, standing still, at the point of a sword, when this humiliation is applied; but, the expression is "to-be-sent-under"--at least implying movement.